# How to get PHP to choose one div or another depending on device screen size

Tags: javascript, php, css, responsive-design

At the minute I have a PHP script which outputs a 'page title' div. This div incorporates a blur script (blur.js) and is quite slow as it requires lots of processing.

This means that pages take slightly longer to load on desktop, but much longer on mobile!

I can use a mediaquery to hide this div (using `display: none`) and instead display a simple text title, but in the background the div still gets processed.

Is there any way I could use PHP to choose either the div or the plain title, rather than a media query?  I know this would involve the PHP code having to know the device screen size, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: PHP is server side, i.e. it can't tell the size of your browser screen.  Using javascript or jquery `$(window).width()` would be better suited here, as I'm sure some will answer.

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting. You cannot do with PHP. But a simple idea is, get the screen size using jQuery and append the `<div>` in to your page if the screen size is bigger.

Comment: Instead of trying to monkey patch something why is `blur.js` so slow?

Comment: for detection of screen size . you can use JavaScript `screen.availWidth;` will tell you the Screen size .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect mobile devices by using a User Agent Analyzer but this wont give you the screen size.

You could also use javascript to send the screen size back to your server via AJax and then store a cookie or something for the user.